# How do I copy a MATLAB libsvm model to android application folder

Tags: android, matlab, copy, libsvm

How do I copy the trained libsvm model (I have a file called data.txt) from MATLAB to my phone? I don't know the folders I should save it to and how to load it in my actual app.

I am running the `adb shell` command via my computer and I am in the directory `/data/data/edu.umich.eecs.androidlibsvm`

I can only see these folders:

```
shell@A0001:/data/data/edu.umich.eecs.androidlibsvm $ ls
cache
lib
shell@A0001:/data/data/edu.umich.eecs.androidlibsvm $ cd lib
shell@A0001:/data/data/edu.umich.eecs.androidlibsvm/lib $ ls
libjnilibsvm.so
shell@A0001:/data/data/edu.umich.eecs.androidlibsvm/lib $
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand from your question, you basically want to do 2 things

1. Push filename.extension to your device
2. Access this file from your app i.e read/load it in your app.

So I am going to answer as per the above stages

1. Use adb push command to transfer the file from your system to the device

   `adb push filename.extension /sdcard/0/<public_folder>`

where `<public_folder>` could be ***Download***

2. To read/load this file you only need to use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`

   [Reference Link from Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

**Note** : The whole process can be adapted to work with internal storage too, but I am assuming you want the ***file*** to be publically available to apps.